# Write Hash to CSV file and then read the values back to form a hash

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, export-to-csv

I am banging my head try to resolve an issue I am experiencing with one of my latest projects. Here is the senario:

I am making an call to GoToWebinar API to fetch upcoming webinars. Everything is working fine and the webinars are fetched in the form of hash just like this :

```
[
{
"webinarKey":5303085652037254656,
"subject":"Test+Webinar+One",
"description":"Test+Webinar+One+Description",
"times":[{"startTime":"2011-04-26T17:00:00Z","endTime":"2011-04-26T18:00:00Z"}]
},
{
"webinarKey":9068582024170238208,
"name":"Test+Webinar+Two",
"description":"Test Webinar Two Description",
"times":[{"startTime":"2011-04-26T17:00:00Z","endTime":"2011-04-26T18:00:00Z"}]
}
]
```

I have created a rake task which we are going to run once a day to populate the CSV file with this hash and then the CSV file is read in the controller action to populate the views.

Here is my code to populate the CSV file :

```
g = GoToWebinar::API.new()
@all_webinars = g.get_upcoming_webinars
CSV.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/upcoming_webinars.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  @all_webinars.each do |webinar|
    webinar.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem}
  end
end
```

I need some help in figuring out a way to save the information received in the form of hashed to be saved in the CSV file in such a way that the order is preserved and also a way to read to the information back from the CSV file that it populates the hash in the controller action in the very same way.

Comment: CSVs and Hashes are trying to accomplish two different things, so they're not really going to translate back and forth seamlessly. For example, the value for "times" in the hash is itself and array of another hash; that means each item you're trying to put into the CSV (a one-level deep data structure) is at least three levels deep. Is there some reason you couldn't just save the hash as a JSON file and read that back in? Otherwise you're going to need to pull apart the hash and map the values to specific columns in the CSV, which would be very fragile.

Comment: First of all, the hash you are talking about is a JSON string and not a Ruby hash. Either save the string as a JSON string in a JSON file or, you can convert it into a Ruby hash and `marshal` the object and then store the resulting string in a file. While reading the file, you need to "un-marshal" the string which results in a Ruby hash. [Ruby Marshalling](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From What I have learnt from all the examples and work done to accomplish this I think the best way to go around this type of functionality is to create a rake task to and populate the database with the information and use the information saved to populate the views.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the keys of the hash (since they are constant) as the headers for your CSV file. Then push each element on as you are doing.

```
g = GoToWebinar::API.new()
@all_webinars = g.get_upcoming_webinars
headers= @all_webinars.keys
CSV.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/upcoming_webinars.csv", "wb", headers: headers) do |csv|
  @all_webinars.each do |webinar|
    webinar.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem}
  end
end
```

You are going to want to make sure, however, that any data inside the hash values is flattened. That hash inside of an array for times needs to be dealt with (perhaps just remove times and have a startTime and endTime key in the hash).